How can I disable keyboard/mouse input?
I'm using ImGui v1.84, I wanted to disable any sort of keyboard or mouse input while my ImGui window is open. How can I do this? (I'm fairly new to ImGui, & using Kiero Hook Dx11)
I modified the WndProc function to handle input events but I don't think I did it correctly?
LRESULT __stdcall WndProc(const HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_KEYDOWN && wParam == VK_INSERT) {
        showImGuiWindow = !showImGuiWindow;
        ImGui::GetIO().MouseDrawCursor = showImGuiWindow; // To Toggle Mouse Cursor
        return true;
    }

    if (showImGuiWindow) {
        if (ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam))
            return true;

        // Block all keyboard and mouse input events when ImGui window is open?
        if (uMsg == WM_KEYDOWN || uMsg == WM_KEYUP || uMsg == WM_CHAR ||
            uMsg == WM_MOUSEMOVE || uMsg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || uMsg == WM_LBUTTONUP ||
            uMsg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || uMsg == WM_RBUTTONUP || uMsg == WM_MBUTTONDOWN ||
            uMsg == WM_MBUTTONUP || uMsg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL || uMsg == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return CallWindowProc(oWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


Why do you think that you didn't do it correctly? What is the problems you're having?

Apologies, I see my mistake, I was having issues with mouse input, when I inject my dll to my game, I am still able to look around, and I don't want to be able to do that.

Have you considered that your target process might not be relying on the WndProc to process input? The game loop can just as well query the mouse position itself.
